# Laravel select query with array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I get a string like this

```
$str = 'What is a typical day like';
```

Now I want to search the DB for every word this string contains.

```
What
is
a
...
```

I'm trying the following:

```
$var = Input::get('search');
// first try was $data = explode(' ',$var);
$data = array(str_replace(' ',',',$var));

$result = Faq::whereIn('heading', $data)->orWhereIn('wording',$data)->get();

return Response::json(array('name' => $result));
```

Both gives me no results, but each of those words is at least 4 times in the database. Where is my error?

Comment: what happen with first try explode ?

Comment: The same, no result @AnandPatel

Comment: but you heading do not match with exact value like is, a etc thats why you need to use where('heading', 'LIKE', '%value%')->get()   something like this, not exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode()` is the right function to use here, as it will split all your words into an array properly. This will only not work if you're looking for (as an example) a name like "Mary Ann" or something with a space in it. As for the query, if you're trying to search every column for every word, that might be a little tricky... BUT you could do something like this:

```
$query = Faq->select(); // Initializes the query
foreach($data AS $value){
  $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ', column_1, column_2, ...)"), 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
}
$faqs = $query->get(); // Runs the query
```

The logic behind that is `CONCAT_WS` on all the columns to create a giant string of all the values of all the colmuns, then querying that string to match each word in your `$data` array.

This kind of query (ie searching/filtering results based on input) is much easier when you know what column you're looking for. An associative array of `column_name => value_to_find` makes this much easier as you can do:

```
foreach($data AS $key => $value){
  $query->where($key, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
}
$faqs = $query->get();
```

**Edited Example**

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| address  | city     | province |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 123 Main | Toronto  | Ontario  |
| 123 2nd  | Montreal | Quebec   |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Given this test data, calling `CONCAT_WS(" ", address, city, province))` in your SQL would result in a string of `123 Main Toronto Ontario` and `123 2nd Montreal Quebec`. If your search array was something like `[0] => 123, [1] => Toronto, [2] => Ontario` I think you'd (maybe?) get 1 result as `$query->where(...)` followed by another `$query->where(...)` produces a `WHERE ... AND WHERE ...` structure. As I mentioned in my edit, add a counter to the foreach:

```
$counter = 0;
$query = Faq->select(); // Initializes the query
foreach($data AS $value){
  if($counter == 0){
    $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ', column_1, column_2, ...)"), 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'); 
  } else {
    $query->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ', column_1, column_2, ...)"), 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'); 
  }
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect query for narrowing down the searches +1 and thank you, but (with the little tests I just did), it seems like both words I search for need to be in the string. Is there a possibility to find all the strings occuring in whatever column? What do you think?

Comment: Hmm... It shouldn't be like that. Let me make a quick edit to show an example.

Comment: Yeah, I thought concat would find everything, too.

Comment: As an example, if I search for "What" only, I get 6 results, but if I search for "What RBC" I only get 3 results, though I excpected at least 6, too.

Comment: Well, the query would be structed as `WHERE ... AND WHERE ...` as that's what Laravel does. To do an `OR WHERE` you'd need a counter in your `foreach` that, after the first result, would change `$query->where(...)` into `$query->orWhere(...)`

Comment: This is what I need, thank you, you pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static function getProductSearch($words){

        $word = explode(' ', $words);

        $value = Product::where('active', 'Y');
        foreach ($word as $key) {
            $value->where('title', 'like', "%$key%");
        }
            $data = $value->get();
        return $data;
    }
```